# Infinite Sequence of requests in Finagle with Future

Tags: scala, future, finagle

I have an HTTP API endpoint that I need constantly check for new values. Luckily, it's supports long polling. So the idea is that I need to implement 'an infinite loop' where I do a request, wait for a response (at most 10mins), get some value from response and produce a side-effect by storing them somewhere, make another request.

Given that I have some function the call to which will start this 'infinite loop' I also need to return a `Closable` to satisfy Finagle API I'm integrating with so the process can be interrupted. If HTTP request fails I need to re-try immediately.

Now I need to figure out how to implement this with `Future`s in Finagle. I wonder whether I can user a recursion by applying transform to response Future?.. Or am I missing something and there is a more straightforward way to do it in Finagle?

Thanks!

Comment: I've had a similar problem, but I've solved it with http4s/scalaz-stream `time.awakeEvery.map(<do http call>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I can imagine how it (what you described) can be made any more straightforward than recursive:

```
  def keepCalling: Future[Unit] = makeRequest
    .flatMap { response => 
       processResponse(response)
       if(cancelled) Future.Unit else keepCalling
     }
```

Note, that this is actually *not* recursive in the traditional sense, as we should normally expect (with some reservations) only one instance of `keepCalling` to be on stack at any given time, since the "recursive" invocation happens on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks! So, does it mean that memory consumption will grow with each cycle? Or Scala will take care of that?

Also, how would you handle `canceled`? A `var`? Or there some better way to do that?

Comment: I don't see anything about this case that suggests you should worry about memory consumption any more than in any other application. I mean, you _do_ need to worry about it, and it _will_ grow if you are not releasing the refs properly, I just don't see why this case should make you any more worried than any other. As for handling `cancelled` ... yeah, a `var`, I guess. No need for anything fancier in a simple case like this. Just be sure to make it `volatile`, so that updates made in one thread are properly seen by the other.

Comment: Super thanks! And the last question what if `makeRequest ` will return a failing future? The 'loop' will brake? Should we use something else rather then `flatMap` to have a 'retry'?

Comment: sure. You can can a `.rescue` or `.handle` inserted before `.flatMap` to handle the exceptions.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this: https://gist.github.com/Ashald/87684ccd50ed66d6ce3b27b4f68fb61b
(sorry I wasn't able to put that snippet properly into the comment)
Does it look reasonable? Thanks!